# Ios build fails if deployment target is set to 10.0.0

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework

I have created application with ionic and everything is working fine when Deployment target is set to 11.0.0 or above.

But as soon as I set iOS deployment target to 10.0.0 or 10.3.0 am getting build failure with below error message.

```
ld: library not found for -lGoogleToolboxForMac
```

Comment: What’s the question?

Comment: iOS 10 is supported by more architectures than iOS 11. Your framework is probably missing slices.

Comment: Are you using ionic 4?

Comment: i'm getting the same thing in ionic 4

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this update command?

`ionic cordova platform update ios`

Let me now if this works

Comment: You can also try to remove `node-modules` manually folder and then `npm cache clear` - `npm update` - `npm install`

Comment: except cache clear every command is running, as we are running it with jenkins as well and, we are able to do build but can't achieve here strangely.